# the closure of subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have read the following sentece on a lecture notes:

> If $G\subset\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is a subgroup then its
> topological closure $\overline{G}$ is a topologically closed subgroup.
> $\overline{G}$ is obviously topologically closed, and I'm
> claiming that it's still a subgroup.

Now, I guess the topology is a metric topology (on $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ all metrics  are equivalent), but I cannot see how it is true: as it is, it seems a false statement to me.

For example, if $G=\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ then its closure is all the space of $n\times n$ matrixes, which is not a group.

Or if I consider the subgroup of diagonal matrix of the form $\lambda\mathrm{Id}_n$, $0\neq\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, then the zero matrix is in the closure so it is not a group (with respect to the matrix multiplication).

I would need the assumption that $\overline{G}\subset\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ to prove that it is a subgroup.

Am I missing something?

Comment: If $G=\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$ then $\overline{G}=G$.

Comment: The closure is understood inside $GL(n, {\mathbb R})$. The claim that the closure of a subgroup is again a subgroup holds for general topological groups.

Comment: I disagree. On $\mathrm{GL}(1,\mathbb{R})=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x\neq0\}$ you have that the closure is $\mathbb{R}$ but $0$ has no inverse. On $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ you can take a diagonal matrix with 1 and a $\epsilon$ on the other entry, which converge to a singular matrix.

Comment: Closed, as defined on that notes, is if any convergence sequence (of element of the set) has limit in the set. And closure is defined as the set plus the limit points.

Comment: You can disagree, but that is what is meant: If you take the closure of $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ in $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$, you get $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ again. (If you take the closure in $\mathbb R$, you do get $\mathbb R$; but again, that is not what is meant by “closure” here.)

Comment: Without looking at your notes, I have no idea what was said there, but there is always a chance that the notes were sloppily written. In this case, complain to the instructor.

Comment: Yes, I got the point. There is some discrepancy on that notes.

Comment: That definition of closure is fine, but it (implicitly) depends on which things are points that can be limits. In this setting, we work purely in $\operatorname{GL}(n)$ and non-invertible matrices simply don’t exist as potential limit points. (Similar to how a sequence in the reals can converge to infinity, but usually infinity is not in the closure of $\mathbb R$ because we don’t consider it a valid point. Which points are valid as limits depends on the context.)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the fact that, when the author of those notes wrote about $\overline G$, what it was meant was its closure in $GL(n,\Bbb R)$.

Besides, it is not true that, in $GL(n,\Bbb R)$ all metrics are equivalent. The usual metric that it is used on $GL(n,\Bbb R)$ is the one for which$$d\bigl((a_{ij})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n},(b_{ij})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}\bigr)=\sqrt{\sum_{i,j=1}^n(a_{ij}-b_{ij})^2}.$$

Comment: Good point. I meant norm. For closed, as reported on the other comment, is not specified it is in $\mathrm{GL}$. That exactly the assumption I want to use